# SSD got unmounted by itself while OS is running

Tags: boot, mount, ssd

While I was working on my laptop suddenly froze. I had to turn off and then turn it on from the button... When I turned it on I saw that my ssd isn't mounted and the OS is there..

I see this message:

```
The disk drive for /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is not ready yet or not present. Continue to wait, or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

Somehow I managed to enter in TTY mode by clicking `ctrl+alt+F1` but I was able to log only like guest. Then with `df -h` I saw that ssd drive isn't mounted.. I can't do anything like `guest` and I can't log in with my administrator account it's keep telling me that password is incorrect.

So what can I do now?

I'm using Ubuntu 16. Also I've run some tests which are from BIOS and they show that both HDD's are good and working.. normal drive + ssd drive..